# Why Laravel Dusk do not provide a way to authenticate the user?

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

Cannot authenticate the user to API at the beginning of each test by using Laravel Dusk with Laravel Passport.

I've tried:
`$this->actingAs(User::find(1), 'api');`
`$browser->loginAs(User::find(1));`
`Passport::actingAs($this->user);`

The only way I can authenticate the user is to repeat the login logic at the beginning of each test, but I really hope there's a more straight-forward & faster way to do it.

```php
$browser->visit('/login')
         ->type('@email', 'example@email.com')
         ->type('@password', 'password')
         ->click('@login-button')
         ->waitForLocation('/')`
```

I'm expecting there are a LOT cleaner and faster way to authenticate user before each test.

But the question is, are there?

At least by reading the docs and googling, it seems like there isn't, I hope I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can login using `$browser->loginAs($user)`, but you will have to create the user before of course.

What might also be necessary, and I remember fiddling around with that for a long time myself as well, is to commit your database changes before running the test code (i.e. `$this->browse(...)`). This is because of the way a Dusk test is performed. Normal unit tests are all performed in the same process, which uses the same connection and has therefore the same state. A Dusk test is performed using multiple processes, one is like a unit test and one emulates the browser. Therefore changes to a database need to be committed, which does normally happen implicitly when closing a connection (at least for SQLite databases).

The following, very basic test should give you a direction:

```
public function test_home_screen_is_accessible_by_authentication_user(): void
{
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = factory(User::class)->state('dusk')->create();
    DB::commit();

    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($user) {
        $browser->loginAs($user)
            ->visit(new HomePage);
    });
}
```

Comment: That's not the case with the API authentication. You can authenticate the user easily with Dusk if your app uses basic auth. As your example shows. Personally, I use `$this->seed()` to get the users & other necessary stuff, tho. But that's off-topic.

Comment: What do you mean? The unit test part is authenticating using an API of the chrome driver to authenticate.

Comment: Token-based user authentication. It needs to be done by setting up cookies, however, Laravel Dusk does not seem to offer a way to do so, even that Laravel does provide API authentication package, called Passport, which I'm using at this case. I think the only way to do so is to do hacky tricks to manipulate the cookies before each test but that's just sad that it's not baked into the core, or at least documented an ideas of how to achieve it.

Comment: Not sure why you would want to test an API or an interface of an API (SPA) with Dusk. An API is already an interface that you can test well with feature tests. And the SPA should be tested with a JS test framework. So yeah, basically confused.

Comment: I have feature test suites for my API endpoints, etc & test suites for my front-end stuff, but e2e is the last test suite I'm lacking, and Laravel Dusk is for e2e tests. Sure, I'd love to use another software like Cypress, but since my back-end is Laravel, it's simpler to use Laravel Dusk. It's simpler to refresh DB, for example.

Comment: Or at least I thought it would be simpler to use Laravel Dusk

Comment: I've no experience with it, but `$browser->loginAs()` lets you pass a guard as second parameter (`public function loginAs($userId, $guard = null)`). It is not the same as `actingAs()`, which is used for feature tests. If all that doesn't work, I'm the wrong person to help, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, I know and I tried to pass `api` as a guard, but no luck. No worries, thanks for your time. I appreciate it. Maybe I have to repeat the login logic at the beginning of each test till I find a better way to do it.

Comment: I guess that you are developing a SPA as frontend, which means you'd need to somehow set the authentication token in the session store or local storage of your browser (after authenticating a user to create the token). Maybe this can be done via some chrome driver config, but as I said, that's out of my knowledge.